# jQuery: Conversión de script jQuery a CSS

Tags: html, jquery, css

Tengo el siguiente script jQuery que querría convertir -si es posible- a CSS por cuestiones de rendimiento:

```
$(function()
{
    $('.contenedor-top3').mouseenter(function() //Al pasar el ratón por encima
    {
        $(this).css({'transform': 'scale(1.25)', 'zIndex': '3'}); //Agranda la foto elegida
        $('.contenedor-top3').not(this).css({'filter': 'blur(15px)', 'transform': 'scale(0.75)'}); //Difumina las otras dos
        $(this).find('.numero-top3').addClass('shake-slow shake-constant'); //Y hace que vibre el número
    });

    $('.contenedor-top3').mouseleave(function() //Al retirar el ratón, revierte los cambios
    {
        $(this).css({'transform': 'scale(1)', 'zIndex': ''});
        $('.contenedor-top3').not(this).css({'filter': 'blur(0px)', 'transform': 'scale(1)'});
        $(this).find('.numero-top3').removeClass('shake-slow shake-constant');      
    });
});
```

Actúa sobre el siguiente HTML, que se repite 3 veces dentro de un bucle PHP:

```
<div> <!--Bloque con cada una de las fotos del top 3-->

    <form class="contenedor-top3" id="contenedor-top3-<?=$contador?>" data-prueba="prueba" method="post" action="<?=url_base?>recopilatorios/indice">

        <img class="imagen-top3" id="imagen-top3-<?=$contador?>" src="<?=url_base?>recursos/imagenes/autores/<?=$nombre_autor?>.jpg">

        <div class="numero-top3" id="numero-top3-<?=$contador?>" data-contador2="<?=$contador?>"><?=$contador?></div>

        <div class="icono estrella-top3 oculto" id="estrella-top3-<?=$contador?>">R</div>
        
        <div class="nota-top3 oculto" id="nota-top3-<?=$contador?>"><?=$nota_media?></div>

        <div class="referencia-top3" id="referencia-top3-<?=$contador?>"><a href="<?=$foto_autor?>" target="_blank">&copy;</a></div> 

        <div class="texto-top3" id="texto-top3-<?=$contador?>">
            <span class="cancion-top3"><?=$titulo_cancion?></span>
            <span> de </span>  
            <span class= "autor-top3"><?=$nombre_autor_orden?></span> 
            <span class="ano-top3">(<button class="boton-enlace" role="link" name="recopilatorio" value="<?=$recopilatorio?>"><?=$ano?></button>)</span>
        </div>
                            
    </form>

</div>
```

Que hace que se vea de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado a comentar la primera línea, tanto del `mouseenter()` como del `mouseleave()`, que escala y aplica `z-index`:

```
$(this).css({'transform': 'scale(1.25)', 'zIndex': '3'});
$(this).css({'transform': 'scale(1)', 'zIndex': ''});
```

Y a usar en su lugar la siguiente regla CSS:

```
.contenedor-top3:hover {
    transform: scale(1.25); 
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Sin embargo, sólo funciona sobre la primera foto (sea la 1, la 2 o la 3) en que pruebas a hacer `hover`; en la siguiente que haces `hover` (sea la que sea de las restantes) deja de funcionar y, si vuelves a hacerlo sobre la primera, tampoco funciona ya.

Por otro lado, ¿sería posible difuminar las dos fotos restantes y aplicar la clase de CSShake mediante CSS "a pelo"?

Os lo añado en forma de "snippet" (falta añadir Web Symbols, que no la he encontrado en línea):

```js
/* Aplica estilos específicos a las fotos del top 3 al pasar el ratón por encima de una de ellas */

$(function()
{
    $('.contenedor-top3').mouseenter(function() //Al pasar el ratón por encima
    {
        //$(this).css({'transform': 'scale(1.25)', 'zIndex': '3'}); //Agranda la foto elegida
        $('.contenedor-top3').not(this).css({'filter': 'blur(15px)', 'transform': 'scale(0.75)'}); //Difumina las otras dos
        $(this).find('.numero-top3').addClass('shake-slow shake-constant'); //Y hace que vibre el número
    });

    $('.contenedor-top3').mouseleave(function() //Al retirar el ratón, revierte los cambios
    {
        //$(this).css({'transform': 'scale(1)', 'zIndex': ''});
        $('.contenedor-top3').not(this).css({'filter': 'blur(0px)', 'transform': 'scale(1)'});
        $(this).find('.numero-top3').removeClass('shake-slow shake-constant');      
    });
});
```

```css
/* COLORES */

:root {
    --color1: pink;
    --color2: mediumvioletred;
    --color3: purple;
}


/* FUENTES */

@font-face {
    font-family: "Web Symbols";
    src: url(../fuentes/WebSymbols-Regular.otf);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


/* ESTILOS GENERALES */

.oculto {
    display: none;
}

.icono {
    font-family: "Web Symbols";
} /*Convierte letras en iconos*/


/* BOTONES Y ENLACES */

.boton-enlace {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
    background: none;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
.boton-enlace:hover {
    color: var(--color2);
}
.boton-enlace:active {
    color: var(--color3);
}
.boton-enlace:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
} /*Simula un enlace a partir de un botón*/


/* TOP 3 GENERAL */

.contenedor-top3 {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.contenedor-top3:hover {
    transform: scale(1.25); 
    z-index: 3;
}
.contenedor-top3:hover .nota-top3, .contenedor-top3:hover .estrella-top3 {
    display: unset;
}
.contenedor-top3:hover .texto-top3 > .ano-top3 {
    color: mediumvioletred;
} /*Cualquier contenedor*/

#contenedor-top3-1 {
    margin-top: 75px;
    z-index: 2;
}
#contenedor-top3-1:hover img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px 20px #ffff9e;
}
#contenedor-top3-1:hover .numero-top3 {
    color: gold;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 14px yellow;
} /*Contenedor 1*/

#contenedor-top3-2 {
    top: 300px;
    left: 530px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#contenedor-top3-2:hover img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px 20px grey;
}
#contenedor-top3-2:hover .numero-top3 {
    color: silver;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 4px gainsboro;
} /*Contenedor 2*/

#contenedor-top3-3 {
    top: 610px;
    left: 140px;
}
#contenedor-top3-3:hover img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px 20px bisque;
}
#contenedor-top3-3:hover .numero-top3 {
  color: #CD7F32;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 4px bisque;
} /*Contenedor 3*/

.imagen-top3 {
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
#imagen-top3-3 {
    margin-bottom: 75px;
}

.numero-top3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  color: var(--color2);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 75px;
    font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 4px var(--color1);
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
} 
#numero-top3-1, #numero-top3-3 {
    left: 30px;
}
#numero-top3-2 {
    right: 50px;
} /*Puesto en la clasificación*/

.estrella-top3 {
    position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  color: #f0ad4e;
  font-size: 4em;
} 
#estrella-top3-1, #estrella-top3-3 {
    right: 40px;
}
#estrella-top3-2 {
    left: 40px;
} /*Estrella que sirve de fondo a la nota media*/

.nota-top3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 53px;
    color: sienna;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#nota-top3-1, #nota-top3-3 {
    right: 62.5px;
}
#nota-top3-2 {
    left: 62.5px;
} /*Nota media en sí*/

.referencia-top3 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
.referencia-top3 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
.referencia-top3 a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--color1);
} 
#referencia-top3-3 {
    margin-bottom: 75px;
} /*Enlace que redirige a la web de la que se ha tomado la fotografía*/

.texto-top3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: powderblue;
  border: 2.5px solid lightblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 87.5%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
#texto-top3-3 {
    margin-bottom: 75px;
}

.cancion-top3 {
    color: var(--color3);
  font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.autor-top3 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.ano-top3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
} /*Año*/

.boton-vamos {
    margin-top: 517.5px;
    margin-left: 370px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    
    <head>

        <title>50 años de Era Pop</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

        <!-- Google Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rock+Salt&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

        <!-- CSShake -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://csshake.surge.sh/csshake.min.css"/>

        <!-- Animsition -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animsition/4.0.2/js/animsition.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../recursos/js/animsition.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animsition/4.0.2/css/animsition.min.css"/> 

        <!-- Charts.js -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>

        <!-- Sweet Alert-->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
        
        <!-- JS propio -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../recursos/js/audio_youtube.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../recursos/js/scripts.js"></script>

        <!-- jQuery Migrate -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        
        <!-- CSS propio -->
        <link href="../recursos/css/estilos.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="../recursos/css/estrellas.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="css/estrella.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    </head>

    <body>

    <main class="container">

    <section class="fotos" style="max-height: 1085px;"> <!--Sección con las tres fotos del top 3-->

        <div> <!--Bloque con la foto 1-->

          <form class="contenedor-top3" id="contenedor-top3-1" data-prueba="prueba" method="post" action="">

            <img class="imagen-top3" id="imagen-top3-1" src="https://bit.ly/3bKioJU">

            <div class="numero-top3" id="numero-top3-1" data-contador2="1">1</div>

            <div class="icono estrella-top3 oculto" id="estrella-top3-1">R</div>

            <div class="nota-top3 oculto" id="nota-top3-1">4,6</div>

            <div class="referencia-top3" id="referencia-top3-1"><a href="https://bit.ly/3bKioJU" target="_blank">&copy;</a></div> 

            <div class="texto-top3" id="texto-top3-1>>
              <span class="cancion-top3">Ace of spades</span>
              <span> de </span>  
              <span class= "autor-top3">Motörhead</span> 
              <span class="ano-top3">(<button class="boton-enlace" role="link" name="recopilatorio" value="">1980</button>)</span>
            </div>

          </form>

        </div>
        
        <div> <!--Bloque con la foto 2-->

          <form class="contenedor-top3" id="contenedor-top3-2" data-prueba="prueba" method="post" action="">

            <img class="imagen-top3" id="imagen-top3-2" src="https://bit.ly/3q8lCeK">

            <div class="numero-top3" id="numero-top3-2" data-contador2="2">2</div>

            <div class="icono estrella-top3 oculto" id="estrella-top3-2">R</div>

            <div class="nota-top3 oculto" id="nota-top3-2">4,1</div>

            <div class="referencia-top3" id="referencia-top3-2"><a href="https://bit.ly/3q8lCeK" target="_blank">&copy;</a></div> 

            <div class="texto-top3" id="texto-top3-2">
              <span class="cancion-top3">Best of you</span>
              <span> de </span>  
              <span class= "autor-top3">Foo Fighters</span> 
              <span class="ano-top3">(<button class="boton-enlace" role="link" name="recopilatorio" value="">2005</button>)</span>
            </div>

          </form>

        </div>
        
        <div> <!--Bloque con la foto 3-->

          <form class="contenedor-top3" id="contenedor-top3-3" data-prueba="prueba" method="post" action="">

            <img class="imagen-top3" id="imagen-top3-3" src="https://bit.ly/3onioCO">

            <div class="numero-top3" id="numero-top3-3" data-contador2="3">3</div>

            <div class="icono estrella-top3 oculto" id="estrella-top3-3">R</div>

            <div class="nota-top3 oculto" id="nota-top3-3">3,9</div>

            <div class="referencia-top3" id="referencia-top3-3"><a href="https://bit.ly/3onioCO" target="_blank">&copy;</a></div> 

            <div class="texto-top3" id="texto-top3-3">
              <span class="cancion-top3">Town called Malice</span>
              <span> de </span>  
              <span class= "autor-top3">The Jam</span> 
              <span class="ano-top3">(<button class="boton-enlace" role="link" name="recopilatorio" value="1980">1980</button>)</span>
            </div>

          </form>

        </div>

            <button class="boton-vamos btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-decadas" type="submit">¡Vamos!</button>

      </section> <!--Fin de la sección de fotos-->

    </main>
    
    </body>

</html>
```

Un saludo y gracias por adelantado.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a convertir, por ejemplo, `$("selector").css({"color":"red"})` a `selector{color:red}`? Además, hay cosas (como el `addClass`) que no se pueden hacer solo con CSS como tal y tendrías que emplear jQuery

Comment: Lo que quiero es prescindir de ese script jQuery, y que toda su funcionalidad, si es posible, sea suplida mediante reglas CSS en mi hoja de estilos.

Comment: Javier yo aquí veo por lo menos dos preguntas, aunque guarden relación. Yo intentaría separarlas.